# Android Swipe for listview

Tags: android, android-listview, swipe, onfling

I did the coding as below:

```
public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment {
    private SlideoutHelper mSlideoutHelper;
    public final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(
            new GestureListener());
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { " First",
                        " Second", " Third", " Fourth", " Fifth", " Sixth",
                        " Seventh", " Eighth", " Ninth", " Tenth" }));
         getListView().setCacheColorHint(0);
         getListView().setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {

                    return gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // ((MenuActivity)getActivity()).getSlideoutHelper().close();

        Context con = v.getContext();

        if (position == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(con, "First Clicked", 5).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(con, "Clicked", 5).show();
        }
    }
    public class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
        private final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 2000;

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {

            if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                System.out.println("flingggggggggg");
                 mSlideoutHelper.close();


                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not work. Please help me. How can I get the swipe option in this view?

Comment: what is going work explain your problem

Comment: what you exactly want to do. no one could find the problem by reading _your_ code.

Comment: i"m doing ribbon menu using fragments. I did the coding for all that. Now i need to give swipe option in the listview for swipe from left to right.

Comment: thanks everyone. Me itself find out the solution and works properly.

Comment: @RIJORV, post your solution as answer to this question in order to help other people which may have same problem

Comment: @RIJO R V, Hey will you please put solution as i am also facing same problem,it will be great help for me. Thanks.